# Choose ASP.NET .sln (one time) save directory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

When creating a new asp.net web site, Visual Studio automatically saves the .sln file and .vs directory in C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Site_Name after I've specified, say, c:\Users\Me\My_Websites\This_Website\ as the directory for the website.

How do I either get the solution to work with the website after copy/pasting the .sln and /.vb into the same directory as the website, specify the save path of the solution so that it's in the same directory, or get the solution and the website into the same directory somehow?

I don't want it set a new default directory, because I'm a student, and have a lot of projects on the go at a time, and I have to zip them up hand them over for marking or to a group member in a project, and also it seems to make sense to have them together.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

**Start with a Blank Solution**

1. First create a blank `Solution`, which you can save anywhere you want in the file system.

   File > New Project > Other Project Types > Visual Studio Solutions > Blank Solution
2. Then just add new `Projects` to the `Solution` in the same Solution folder (in reality doesn't have to be, but that's not what you want, and it if at some point, you'll go with some source control, keeping things organized this way will save time/work/headaches)

If you have existing projects you can copy the entire existing folder structure of the project (including the all important `.csproj` or `.vbproj` file, into the newly created Blank Solution folder, and instead of Adding a **new** project, Add and **existing project** and select the `.cs`or`.vb` `proj` files.

If you're just experimenting, I'd advise you to just `Copy` first (instead of `Move`) so you can always go back to a "working" state.

Note: you don't actually have to copy the existing `.sln` file for these existing projects. It won't really harm anything, but it will save confusion once you view the folder structure in Explorer/Finder (so you don't have a bunch of .sln files).

You can try experimenting and examine how VS creates the folder structures (`Projects` under `Solutions`), and if you're comfortable, you can

**Edit the `.sln` file**

You can edit the `.sln` file itself in any text editor - you'll see the projects referenced according to its *relative* location to the `.sln` file.

Do this with VS closed (or at least no solution opened)...

e.g.

These show 2 projects in the Solution

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version xxx
....(skipping for brevity)...

Project("{A GUID}") = "The Project Name", "SomeFolder\MyProject.csproj", "{A GUID}"
EndProject

Project("{Another GUID}") = "Another Project Name", "SomeFolder2\AnotherMyProject.csproj", "{Another GUID}"
EndProject
```

Hth.